# 404 for all routes with included locale - NextJS with next-i18next

Tags: reactjs, localization, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

Hi I am following the docs from here: [github docs](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next)

, but all URLs with locales return 404.
For the example:

- localhost:3000/de/second-page = 404
- localhost:3000/en/second-page = 404
- localhost:3000/de = 404
- localhost:3000/en = 404

  - same for the default locale.
- localhost:3000/second-page = 200
- localhost:3000 = 200

I guess, this is because there is no `pages/de/second-page.js`, for the example, but what's the purpose then of this library, if it doesn't solve this problem.

I have searched a lot and I know about `localSubpaths`, but seems that it doesn't work:

```
module.exports = new NextI18Next({
otherLanguages: ['fr'],
//localeSubpaths: localeSubpathVariations[localeSubpaths],
localeSubpaths: {
    de: 'de',
    en: 'en',
  }
})
```

It doesn't work in my app, but it doesn't work in their sample, too: [their sample](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/tree/master/examples/simple)

Comment: You probably didn't configured the middleware properly, you can check this by creating a <Link href="/de/second-page"/>client side nav</Link>

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked these two steps ?

> After creating and exporting your NextI18Next instance, you need to
> take the following steps to get things working:
>
> Create an _app.js file inside your pages directory, and wrap it with
> the NextI18Next.appWithTranslation higher order component (HOC). You
> can see this approach in the examples/simple/pages/_app.js. Your app
> component must either extend App if it's a class component or define a
> getInitialProps if it's a functional component (explanation here).
>
> Create a next.config.js file inside your root directory if you want to
> use locale subpaths. You can see this approach in the
> examples/simple/next.config.js (Next.js 9.5+ required).

```
const { nextI18NextRewrites } = require('next-i18next/rewrites')

const localeSubpaths = {
  de: 'de',
  en: 'en',
};

module.exports = {
  rewrites: async () => nextI18NextRewrites(localeSubpaths),
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    localeSubpaths,
  },
}
```